# Problem calculating multivariable limit.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Can anyone help me calculate:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 6):

$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \left| x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\right)\right |  = \lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} | x| \left|\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\right)\right| \leq \lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} | x|=0$